best practice for keybinding using use-package and evil
What is best practice to define keybindings using use-package and evil?
How is it possible – for example – to bind "M-j" to (evil-)escape?

A "What is best practice" question invites opinion-based answers and so is off-topic for this site.

Okay. However, a constructive answer, how to get the keybindings right, would already help.

Please delete the question and post a different one for your keybinding question. As posed here it's not clear. Is (evil)escape a command? Just what are you trying to bind key M-j to? Questions need to be clear to be accepted. Thx.

@Alois: there is on Melpa the package evil-escape which will help you to set the key combination very easy: (setq evil-escape-sequence "jk"). Please note that is easy to type than M-j(is not vimi-ish); some other people prefer "jj". See also the packagesevil-collectionsandevil-leader`.
